# Macro code correction

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro for use in Excel and it does some autofills for me. It keeps going through column B as well:

```
Sub Autofill()
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Unmerge
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
With Range(Range("A8"), Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1))
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Can the code be changed to only look at column A?

Comment: Does this run for you? I get an error since you're using a -1 column offset in column A.  Do you want to run your `.SpecialCells` in all cells in column A?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, this with statement:

```
With Range(Range("A8"), Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1))
```

looks at column A and B

starting at `Range("A8")` and ending at the last *used* cell in column B `Cells(Rows.Count,3)` - last row in column C - `.End(xlup)` - first used cell from bottom of column C - `.Offset(,-1)` - offset one column to the left (column B).

To make it column A only, just write this:

```
With Range(Range("A8"), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```